# Storing arrays withing arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a project right now that requires me to work with and store millions of different doubles. So I figure the most effective way to store all of these values would be in sets of arrays within arrays. but i have no idea how to do this. Plus i have to feed values into the lower level arrays and don't yet know an effective way of doing this.

The below is an attempt at explaining what I'm going for (This is not code, but the website thought it was):

```
L01 = [1,2,3]
L02 = [3,2,1]
L03 = [2,3,1]
L04 = [1,3,2]

L11 = [L01,L02]
L12 = [L03,L04]

L2 = [L11,L12]
```

So far I have only come up with this, and you should see why it doesn't work. I'm still pretty new to programming so please explain what I should be doing:

```
    //Stores the weight values attached to an individual neuron 
    public double[] NeuronWeights = new double[321];

    //Stores the NeuronWeights[] for an individual layer with incoming weights
    public double[][] LayerWeight = new double[321][];

    //Stores all of the LayerWeight[] in the network
    public double[][][] TotalWeights = new double[11][][];

    public void InitializWeights()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TotalWeights.Length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = 0; j < LayerWeight.Length; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 0; k < NeuronWeights.Length; k++)
                {
                    Random r = new Random();

                    //Creating randome values to fill first level

                    if (r.Next(0, 2) > 0)
                    {
                        NeuronWeights[k] = r.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
                    }

                    else NeuronWeights[k] = 0.0;

                }

                LayerWeight[j][] = NeuronWeights[];
            }

            TotalWeights[i][][] = LayerWeight[][];
        }
    }
}
```

To add more detail; I'm trying to generate and store 321 doubles ,within the range of (-1, 1), 321 time per "layer". Then do that for all 11 "layers". this information  then needs to be called on to assign values for 321 other doubles, 11 times.

Comment: Can you further specify _does not work_? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: Your *arrays within arrays* are known as *multi-dimensional arrays*, which should give you something to search for using `[c#]` (including the brackets)  here or `c-sharp` via Google.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Unless all neurons, layers, and networks are completely described by a single number, you probably need to create a `Neuron` class containing a `List<double> Weight`, a `Layer` class containing a `List<Neuron> Neurons`, and a `Network` class containing `List<Layer> Layers`. Please describe your goal instead of how you have decided to implement your goal.

Comment: side note to the question, just an observation, is `r.NextDouble() * 2 - 1` really what you want? `r.NextDouble()` will return something between 0 - 0.99, so by the time you double it and minus 1, you kind of just end up back where you started right?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-dimensional arrays are not the same as arrays of arrays. Try using `List<>` instead:

```
var L01 = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
var L02 = new List<int> { 3,2,1 };
var L03 = new List<int> { 2,3,1 };
var L04 = new List<int> { 1,3,2 };

var L11 = new List<List<int>> { L01,L02 };
var L12 = new List<List<int>> { L03,L04 };

var L2 = new List<List<List<int>>> { L11,L12 };
```

But depending on what you are trying to accomplish, maybe you don't need to nest your `List`s like that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create a structure where there are 11 layers, each with 321 neuron weights?  That doesn't seem to make sense with your initial goal of storing and working with millions of doubles.

If you simply wanted to store a variable number of layers, each with a variable number of recorded weights, you'd set up something like this:

```
List<List<double>> weightData = new List<List<double>>();
```

You can think of a List as a variable-sized array that is expandable as you are going along in your process.  So for each Layer, you'd

```
List<double> currentLayer = new List<double>();
weightData.add(currentLayer);
```

Then for each weight you wanted to add to the layer you'd do something like:

```
double neuronWeight = 17.0;
currentLayer.add(neuronWeight);
```

at the end of the day, weightData will have all your layers and weights within the layers.  If you plan to manipulate the data after loading it, you will need to come up with a scheme to reference the various layers and weights, but I'm not sure what your use case for that is.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, which uses one multi-dimensional array?

```
int totalWeightLength = 11;
int layerWeightLength = 321;
int neuronWeights = 321;
double[,,] TotalWeights = new double[totalWeightLength, layerWeightLength, neuronWeights];
void InitializWeights()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < totalWeightLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < layerWeightLength; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < neuronWeights; k++)
            {
                Random r = new Random();

                //Creating randome values to fill first level

                if (r.Next(0, 2) > 0)
                {
                    TotalWeights[i,j,k] = r.NextDouble() * 2 - 1;
                }

                else TotalWeights[i,j,k] = 0.0;
            }
        }
    }
}

InitializWeights();
Console.WriteLine(TotalWeights[1,34,23]);
Console.WriteLine(TotalWeights[2,84,123]);
Console.WriteLine(TotalWeights[3,39,24]);
Console.WriteLine(TotalWeights[4,27,36]);
```